# Doubts on the Majorana & Weyl conditions compatibility

Tags: majorana-fermions, clifford-algebra

In the appendix B of Polchinski's book there is a discussion on the compatibility between Majorana and Weyl condition.

My doubts are trough this passages:

He starts constructing the basis in $(2k+2)$ dimension with $k= 0,1,2,....$
[image]
using this lower and upper gamma matrix
[image]

Then he defins the following gamma matrix
[image]

after finding the Weyl representation, he says that

[image]

i can't understand this line,why if the anticommutator is zero then we have an irreps?

My second question it's related to the reality of $\Gamma^{a\pm}$, the book says that using (B.1.5) as basis gives real $\Gamma^{a\pm}$ but i can't see how. This implies that the odd $\Gamma^{\mu}$ are purely imaginary and the even ones are real, can we change the form of $\Gamma^{a\pm}$ in order to have even $\Gamma^{\mu}$ purely immaginary and odd $\Gamma^{\mu}$ real? There is a fixed convention?

Comment: I think you mean, $[\Gamma , \Sigma_{\mu\nu} ] = 0$. Also, where does he say that the Weyl representation is irreducible _because_ $\Gamma$ commutes with $\Sigma$? Can you put the exact quote that you are referring to?

Comment: The correct statement would be "The Dirac representation is reducible because $\Gamma$ commutes with $\Sigma$." In dimensions $D=2~\text{mod}~8$, we know that $\Gamma$ commutes with $\Sigma$, but the Weyl representation is NOT irreducible. Your statement is wrong. I'd be very surprised if Polchinski is actually claiming this.

Comment: You can answer your second question yourself by noticing that, e.g. $\Gamma^2 = \Gamma^{1+} + \Gamma^{1-}$ and $\Gamma^3 = - i ( \Gamma^{1+} - \Gamma^{1-} )$.

Comment: i have edited the question reporting the line where he says that $\Gamma$ and $\Sigma_{\mu\nu}$ anticommute

Comment: He is saying that in ODD dimensions, the DIRAC representation is irreducible. No comment is made about Weyl representations (which do not exist in odd dimensions). Though to be fair, the irreducibility thing is also not quite true because you can have Majorana representations in certain dimensions. When that happens, the Dirac rep is not irreducible.

Comment: So he is saying that in ODD dimension, since $\Sigma_{\mu\nu}$ and $\Gamma$ anticommute they can't commute and so the Dirac representation is irreducible? For the second question i can't understand why $\Gamma^{a\pm}$ are real using (8.1.5) basis.

Comment: $\Gamma$ commutes with the Lorentz generators $\Sigma^{\mu\nu}$ _in even dimensions_. Therefore, Dirac rep. is reducible _in even dimensions_. This property does NOT hold in odd dimensions. Therefore, Dirac rep. is irreducible _in odd dimensions_. However, as I have pointed out, this is not exactly true in certain odd dimensions (specifically, when $D=1,3~\text{mod}~8$) due to the existence of Majorana spinors.